# Get friendly URLs with Python or .htaccess

Tags: python, .htaccess, redirect, friendly-url

using Python on a Linux server, I would like to use "smart URLs" also known as "semantic/friendly/SEO URLs" to get content from a python script.  But I don't want to create all the files (one for each items depending on the URL subpath).

The data to use are stored in a python dictionary and here is the file location:

```
http://mysite.com/blog/data.py
```

Now, I use this system to get the content (with .htaccess):

```
http://mysite.com/blog?article=myfirst_article_id
>>> return "The content of myfirst_article"
```

The goal is to do the same thing but without the query string:

```
http://mysite.com/blog/first_article_id
>>> return "The content of myfirst_article"
```

Is it possible to do that with python (and without .htaccess) and how?
If not, how to do it with .htaccess?

Comment: Are you using any python web frameworks?

Comment: @Charles Ma: No. I try to write all from scratch.

Comment: @Thammas All my respect to you! Good luck with that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a web framework. Even a minimal one like Flask will give you proper URL routing with the ability to define your own URL patterns. Plus, it'll almost certainly work *much* faster than executing your Python scripts via CGI.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I'm curious...  Why scripts would be slower?  Do you have some links?

Comment: CGI starts a new python interpreter everytime an URL is accessed. Most Python frameworks use WSGI where that is not the case.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I accept this answer.  I'm using [web.py](http://webpy.org) with FastCGI.  It's easier for me now!

Answer (score 4):

With htaccess you can use this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ /blog/data.py?article=$1 [L]
```

Comment: With this rule, if my pages have links (like mysite.com/blog/12345) Do you know which url will be indexed by search engines?  mysite.com/blog/12345 or mysite/com/blog?article=1234 ?

Comment: make sure that when you link from your other page you only use the "pretty" link and that would be indexed by the search engine...